# How to do scrolling?

Tags: java, selendroid

I have tried with below coding to scroll the mobile web page .But,the scroll doesn't happening,it throws error message as element not found.

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver).scroll(0, 100);
            action.perform();
```

Comment: Share the error message here? @Selvi

Comment: @A1ternat1ve  Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 53.414 sec <<< FAILURE!
scrollArticle(mobileweb.photocentric.ScrollArticleTest)  Time elapsed: 3.896 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen
 at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions.<init>(TouchActions.java:37)
 at mobileweb.photocentric.ScrollArticleTest.scrollArticle(ScrollArticleTest.java:36)

Answer (score 1):

you can easily notice that selendroid does not have scroll. http://selendroid.io/gestures.html
As you can see on project website you should try:

```
#Please import: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions
WebElement pages = driver.findElement(By.id("vp_pages"));
TouchActions flick = new TouchActions(driver).flick(pages, -100, 0, 0);
flick.perform();
```

and if you just want to scroll from top to the down then change:

```
.flick(pages, -100, 0, 0);
```

to

```
.flick(pages, 0, 100, 0);
```